# Why is a BOOL a signed char?

Tags: objective-c

The other day a user reported a bug to me about a toolbar item that was disabled when it should be been enabled. The validation code (simplified for your benefit) looked like:

```
- (BOOL) validateToolbarItem: (NSToolbarItem *) toolbarItem {

    NSArray* someArray = /* arrray from somewhere*/

    return [someArray count];
}
```

It took me a few minutes to realize that -count returns a 32-bit unsigned int, while BOOL is an 8-bit signed char. It just so happened that in this case someArray had 768 elements in it, which meant the lower 8-bits were all 0. When the int is cast to a BOOL upon returning, it resolves to `NO`, even though a human would expect the answer to be `YES`.

I've since changed my code to `return [someArray count] > 0;` however, now I'm curious why is BOOL really a signed char. Is that really "better" in some way then it being an int?

Comment: You will often see `!![someArray count]` for exactly this reason (does almost the same thing as `> 0`)

Comment: If you think through your question a little more, you'll see that it's pretty much equivalent to "Why is *any type* not the same as an int?" Because the answers are pretty much the same. Smaller scalar types are there because they don't require the full range of an int. BOOL doesn't even require the full range of a signed char, but there was no smaller type available.

Comment: You really should not assign anything other than the result of boolean expressions to boolean variables, no matter what actual type is used to implement boolean variables. Go check your code for other abominations like this.

Answer (score 12):

The answers given (thus far) focus on why BOOL isn't an int. That answer is pretty clear: a char is smaller than an int, and when Objective-C was designed back in the 80s, shaving off a few bytes was always good.

But your question also seems to be asking, "Why is BOOL signed rather than unsigned?" For that, we can look where BOOL is typedef'ed, in `/usr/include/objc/objc.h`:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
```

So there's an answer: the Objective-C designers didn't want to typedef BOOL to char, because on some systems, under some compilers (and remember that Objective-C predates ANSI C, so C compilers differed), a char was signed, and under some, unsigned. The designers wanted `@encode(BOOL)` to return a consistent value across platforms, so they included the signedness in the typedef.

But that still begs the question: why signed rather than unsigned? I don't have a definitive answer for that; I imagine the reason is that they had to pick one or the other, and decided to go with signed. If I had to further conjecture, I'd say it's because ints are signed by default (that is, if they don't include a signedness qualifier).

Comment: If there is no logics behing the scene, then this is not a logical decision. No answer? That's bad in formal sciences. Randomness shouldn't apply to design decisions. Especially when designing formal languages. Morality? Dunno. But it seems legitimate to wonder if O-C is a worthy language, then.

Comment: @cedbeu: What makes you say there is *no* logic? There's plenty of logic as to why `BOOL` is a `char` of some type. The only thing that's unclear is why it's signed rather than unsigned, either of which is fairly arbitrary in this circumstance (meaning you have to pick one, but it's not a big deal which one is picked).

Comment: True. Just, I don't like the idea. I would tend to think that if you have to take an --even minor-- arbitrary decision, it means there is some flaws in the core design. But you're right it's probably not a big deal, and there are probaly such arbitrary design decisions at some point in every lannguages (brrr).

Answer (score 5):

Throwback to simpler times.

The BOOL type was created back when CPUs naturally worked with 8 bit types, rarely padding to 16 or 32 bits.  Yet, memory was scarce and cramming 1 bit into 4 bytes would actually eat a noticeable chunk of additional memory.

Note that BOOL likely predates C++'s _bool by quite a while (iirc--  they may be about the same age.  When NeXT chose Objective-C, C++ was about the same popularity.).

Answer (score 3):

An obvious answer is that it's four times smaller (on typical 32-bit and 64-bit architectures), and also doesn't have any alignment requirements.

Comment: The irony being that on most compilers / architectures, it will pad out the other 3 bytes so that it can write much faster 32-bit read/writes

Comment: @Paul: I've never seen any compiler pad `char` in structs - can you give an example? It most certainly won't do it in arrays due to contiguous storage requirement.

Comment: struct x { int a; char b; int c; }; sizeof(x) == 12. That's probably what he's referring to.

Comment: @sharth: the padding in that case is to align `c` though, and doesn't have much to do with the type of `b` specifically.

Comment: I'll see if I can find an example via kd, I may be full of it though. You're definitely right wrt arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean value *requires* only a single bit (0 or 1), however standard systems deal with bytes as the smallest unit. A bool represented as a byte, at 8 bits, is 4 times smaller than a 32-bit integer, thus the motivation for byte over integer.

Answer (score 1):

Bools are useful in saving a bit of space and in constraining the value to 0 or 1.  It's a smaller type for the same reason you might use a float over a double, or a short over a long. Just space concerns.

This is why it's a good idea to be explicit with your casting, and in the case of a boolean value, performing an actual logical comparison between two of the same type to net an actual bool instead of a truncated value.

Answer (score 0):

It's smaller, that's all really.